# .htaccess control file rewriting rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following rewriterule:

```
   RewriteRule ^api/(.*)?   api/api.php [QSA,L]
```

so if the url is http://www.test.com/api/... , it will be rerouted to the file api.php inside api folder. This works.

However, I'd like to add another rule such that if url is http://www.test.com/second_api/...  will  reroute to file second_api.php inside the api folder. I don't get that to work.

```
      RewriteRule ^second_api/(.*)?   api/second_api.php [QSA,L]  
      RewriteRule (.*)/second_api/(.*)?   api/second_api.php [QSA,L] 
      RewriteRule ^/second_api/(.*)?   api/second_api.php [QSA,L]
```

Either it's the wrong url or it keep reroute to api.php. I'd like to reroute to second_api.php with the new added rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a check otherwise your first rule gets applied again:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !second_api\.php
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)?   api/api.php [QSA,L]  

RewriteRule ^second_api/(.*)? api/second_api.php [QSA,L]
```